# How to generate entity classes when EF core adds foreign keys?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[image]
[image]
[image]

How should I design entity classes for tables? Classes map their relationships? How should I modify it? I don't want to use code first or DB first, just write code manually to add relationships.

```
 public partial class Ip
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Ip1 { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
 public partial class U
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Pwd { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You have to use DbFirst or CodeFirst approach else, you cannot have the relationship @binbin864

Comment: This is a very broad question, or it's not clear what you're asking. Also, it's not clear what the screen shots are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expect of **Code First** and **Database First** we have **Model First** in entity framework.

**First** idea you can add relation between tables on database (server side handling).

**Second** idea you can write sql query code then execute in SeedData Method. but you need to check relation not exist that table.